# Unable to fetch Subnet ID's | Terraform Plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting below error while executing `Terraform plan`. I am following modules concept here.

Below is my resource `aws_efs_mount_target` and `aws_subnet` blocks.

efs.tf:-

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "master_efs" {
  creation_token   = "master"
  performance_mode = "generalPurpose"
  kms_key_id       = "${data.terraform_remote_state.kms_ebs.outputs.key_arn}"
  encrypted        = "true"
  tags = {
    Name        = "master"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "master_mt" {
  file_system_id  = "${aws_efs_file_system.master_efs.id}"
  count           = "${length(var.availability_zones)}"
  subnet_id      = "${data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.*.id[count.index]}"
  security_groups = [ "${aws_security_group.sg.id}" ]
}

data "aws_subnet" "app_subnet_0" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.cng.id}"
  filter {
    name    = "tag:Name"
    values  = ["${var.search_pattern_app}-0"]
  }
}
```

**Error: Invalid index**

```
     on ../../modules/efs.tf line 16, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "master_mt":
      16:   subnet_id      = "${data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.*.id[count.index]}"
        |----------------
        | count.index is 2
        | data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0 is object with 15 attributes

    The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.


Error: Invalid index



     on ../../modules/efs.tf line 16, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "master_mt":
      16:   subnet_id      = "${data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.*.id[count.index]}"
        |----------------
        | count.index is 1
        | data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0 is object with 15 attributes

    The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

Error: Invalid index

  on ../../modules/efs.tf line 35, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "worker_mt":
  35:   subnet_id      = "${data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.*.id[count.index]}"
    |----------------
    | count.index is 1
    | data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0 is object with 15 attributes

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.


Error: Invalid index

  on ../../modules/efs.tf line 35, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "worker_mt":
  35:   subnet_id      = "${data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.*.id[count.index]}"
    |----------------
    | count.index is 2
    | data.aws_subnet.app_subnet_0 is object with 15 attributes

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm understanding from your code you're are trying to create a mounting point for your EFS for each subnet in VPC (one per availability zone), and to do that you want to Terraform to automatically parse the availability zone and then assign the subnet id for the mount target ?
Apparently the code you wrote is trying to match one of the subnet attribute with the value of the counter, if you just want to add aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.1 to aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.x maybe you can put it that way

```
aws_subnet.app_subnet_0.${count.index}.id
```

Comment: This is still a issue

Answer (score 1):

The [`aws_subnet` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet.html) returns a *single* subnet, not a list and you don't appear to be looping over it with `count`.

If you're expecting multiple subnets to be returned then you probably want the [`aws_subnet_ids` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html) instead.

So if you want to create an EFS mount target in each subnet that matches a subnet filter you could use the following:

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "master_efs" {
  creation_token   = "master"
  performance_mode = "generalPurpose"
  kms_key_id       = "${data.terraform_remote_state.kms_ebs.outputs.key_arn}"
  encrypted        = "true"

  tags = {
    Name        = "master"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "app_subnet" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.cng.id}"

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.search_pattern_app}"
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "master_mt" {
  file_system_id  = "${aws_efs_file_system.master_efs.id}"
  count           = "${length(var.availability_zones)}"
  subnet_id       = "${data.aws_subnet.app_subnet.ids[count.index]}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.sg.id}"]
}
```

This finds all the subnets with a name matching the `search_pattern_app` variable and creates EFS mount targets in each of them.

Comment: I am getting same error.
`Error: Invalid index on ../../modules/efs.tf line 18, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "master_mt":18:   subnet_id      = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.app_subnet.ids[count.index]}" |----------------   | count.index is 1 | data.aws_subnet_ids.app_subnet.ids is set of string with 2 elements.This value does not have any indices.`